# Application.cfm not run in ColdFusion app

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfm

I've got 2 ColdFusion apps built with a similar layout. They were built about the same time. I've recently upgraded my local server to ColdFusion 9. They both work fine locally but when I visit them through my IP one doesn't run the `application.cfm`. The other does. They're both running on the same server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first thought is that on a case-sensitive file system, Application.cfm MUST have a capital A.

Comment: it's no problem about case-sensitive for application.cfm file.

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive, but others systems are.  If you don't capitalize appropriately, you will run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

If your application has an Application.cfc, and an Application.cfm or onRequestend.cfm page, ColdFusion ignores the CFM pages.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=AppEvents_01.html